# Mimic layout of android alarm clock

Tags: android-layout, clock, alarm

I would like to create a layout similar to what the default alarmclock in android has.
What i would like to create is something like this:

> [Android Alarm Clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7C3P.png)

What is beeing used? Is it a ListView, TableLayout or what is it?

Also how do i create those toggle buttons to the left?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It is a listview with custom list items. Each listitem is built up by several other views mostly linear views.

More details in the [source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=summary).

Comment: Hey @Jake, the link you provided appears to be broken.